# Executing a stored procedure inside another one

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
USE tag
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE Graph
   @x VARCHAR(7)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @y VARCHAR(9)
  DECLARE @z VARCHAR(9) 

  SELECT @y = @x;
  SELECT @z = @x;

  IF( (SELECT A.h FROM A 
       LEFT JOIN R ON A.h= R.h
       WHERE  A.x= @x) = '1')
  BEGIN
     EXEC Graph1 @y --> another stored procedure
  END

  IF( (SELECT A.h FROM A 
       LEFT JOIN R ON A.h= R.h
       WHERE  A.x= @x) = '3')
  BEGIN
     EXEC Graph2 @z --> another stored procedure
  END  
END
```

Here I get the following error

> Procedure or function 'Graph1' expects parameter '@y', which was not supplied.
>   Procedure or function 'Graph2' expects parameter '@z', which was not supplied.

But I declared them and assigned the values to the parameter above in the stored procedure. Any suggestions or ideas on the mistake am doing here?

Comment: What is the signature of Graph1 and Graph2?

Comment: Currently they have no digital signatures. They are two procedures I am using for a different purpose and their result is important for my current procedure.

Comment: Not digitial signature, just what is there interface? how many arguments do they have? `exec sp_helptext 'Graph1'` look to see what args it takes?

Comment: Yep it needs three arguments. That's what I was missing yesterday. Figured out the mistake and Its working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
   EXEC Graph1 --> another stored procedure
```

You need to do this:

```
   EXEC Graph1 @y
```

And similarly:

```
   EXEC Graph1 @z
```

Currently you are setting the value of the local variables `@y` and `@z` in the first stored procedure, but you aren't passing them through as parameters to the stored procedures you are calling.

Comment: Probably you made a mistake in the implementation, please edit your post with the code where you tried my suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to execute the ALTER statement before trying the procedure again.   The error you say you aren't getting shouldn't be possible with that code.

Comment: Haha I did execute the alter statement. Not sure where the mistake is either.

Comment: You could try this:   `EXEC Graph1 @y=@y`.   But the code I posted above should work, or at least you should get a different error message.

Comment: If the error message hasn't changed, then I have to assume you are making some mistake in the implementation.   The only way to check that, however, is if you can post a reproducible example.

Comment: It worked. Forgot to declare another variable needed for one of the stored procedures. Thanks!